# Dynamically change location marker based on user's input

Tags: openlayers, markers

I have the following code for displaying OSM with a predefined feature. I am using OpenLayers3:

```
var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });

        var view = new ol.View({
            center: [637125.42195, 8172199.19090669],
            zoom: 14
        });
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point([637125.42195, 8172199.19090669]),
            name: 'Null Island',
            population: 4000,
            rainfall: 500
        });

        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 0.75,
                src: 'https://evernote.com/media/img/getting_started/skitch/android/android-location_icon.png'
            }))
        });

        iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [iconFeature]
        });

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [wmsLayer, vectorLayer],
            target: 'map',
            view: view,
            //controls: []
        });
        map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
            var position = evt.coordinate;
        });
```

How I can change the location of the marker in the click event now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very nice and well considered code. What you have missed is updating the coordinates of the point object in the event, not only storing them in a variable. The easiest way to achieve this is getting the geometry property of the icon and updating it in the `singleclick` event. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/3oj4madx/) to show it.

The main changes are the following:

1: Grabbing the geometry of the feature from the iconFeature object:

```
var iconGeometry = new ol.geom.Point([637125.42195, 8172199.19090669]);

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: iconGeometry,
        name: 'Null Island',
        population: 4000,
        rainfall: 500
    });
```

2: Updating the geometry with the `setCoordinates()` [function](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Point.html#setCoordinates):

```
    map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
        iconGeometry.setCoordinates(evt.coordinate);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you :) Was looking in a documentation for this method, but all the time got solution only for previous version of OpenLayers

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for going the extra mile and making the fiddle.